# Reading .data file using Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am working on a Deep Learning project, the data was provided to me in a file with the ".data" extension. Able to read the data from the file using the Pandas "read_csv" function. I tried to search about the file properties on the web, but i am not clear about the file properties, usage, etc. Here are the few questions i have,

1. What is the ".data" file?
2. How they are created? (Mean exported from any application or database)
3. Is this the correct way to read the ".data" file using the pd.read_csv method? (Tried read_table as well)
4. Is there any other way to read the ".data" file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just ran into a .data file in the wild myself. I've been able to view it in any text editor (notepad, visual studio code, jupyter lab, etc). This helped determine what the separator should be. Mine was not tab-delimited as mrinali mentioned, but that's not to say that there aren't any tab-delimited .data files. Mine was space-delimited, so I just specified this as "sep" in panda's `.read_csv()` method:

```
pd.read_csv('<your_path>', sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 9):

Recently i found a solution for `.data` files using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_fwf("example.data")
```

For more details check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305914/reading-data-files-using-pandas/60305915#60305915).

Answer (score 1):

A DATA file is a data file used by Analysis Studio, a statistical analysis and data mining program. It contains mined data in a plain text, tab-delimited format, including an Analysis Studio file header. DATA files are commonly used to store data for offline data analysis when not connected to an Analysis Studio server, but may also be used in online mode.
Due to their tab-delimited format, DATA files may be imported using pandas via read_csv function once their header information is stripped.

**HOW TO OPEN A .DATA FILE?**

Launch a .data file, or any other file on your PC, by double-clicking it. If your file associations are set up correctly, the application that's meant to open your .data file will open it. It's possible you may need to download or purchase the correct application. It's also possible that you have the correct application on your PC, but .data files aren't yet associated with it. In this case, when you try to open a .data file, you can tell Windows which application is the correct one for that file. From then on, opening a  .data file will open the correct application.

Comment: Thank you Mrinali for the answer, I want to open the file in pandas a method other than read_csv or read_table