# Reading .data files using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Recently i encountered a file with *`.data`* extension and i searched google, i found irrelevant answers. I tried different solutions provided by blogs and websites. Nothing seems helpful. I am providing solution which was suggested to me by my colleague. Before i tried reading with **`read_csv`**.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("example.data")
```

It processed the csv file but with irrelevant data.

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to read `.data` file using pandas is `read_fwf()`. For better knowledge refer [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-fwf-reader).

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_fwf("example.data")
```

By default `data` will not contains columns because in `.data` will contain any columns. In order to get column names we have to pass the column names while reading the file.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_fwf("example.data", names=["col1", "col2"])
print(data.columns)
>>> [col1, col2]
```

Hope this is useful..!!!

Answer (score 0):

I would say treat the .data file as a csv file(for me worked out). In case your column names are missing, just specify them.
I used:

```js
import pandas as pd
DataFrame = pd.read_csv("file.data", names=["columnName", "..." , ".." ])
```