# Reading in a .txt file to get time series from rows of years and columns of monthly values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How could I read in a txt file like the one from
https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/pna.data (example below)

```
 1960  -0.16  -0.22  -0.69  -0.07   0.99   1.20   1.11   1.85  -0.01   0.48  -0.52   1.15
 1961   1.16   0.17   0.28  -1.14  -0.25   1.84  -0.52   0.47   1.10  -1.94  -0.40  -1.54
 1962  -0.74  -0.54  -0.71  -1.50  -1.11  -0.97  -0.36   0.57  -0.83   1.33   0.53  -0.38
 1963   0.09   0.79  -2.04  -0.79  -0.95   0.50  -1.10  -1.01   0.87   0.93  -0.31   1.46
 1964  -0.44   1.36  -1.31  -1.30  -2.27   0.27   0.20   0.83   0.92   0.80  -0.78  -2.03
 1965  -0.92  -1.03  -0.80  -1.07  -0.42   1.89  -1.26   0.32   0.36   1.42  -0.81  -1.56
```

into a pandas dataframe to plot as a time series, for example from 1960-1965 with each value column (corresponding to months) being plotted? I rarely use .txt's

Comment: Try this: ```data = pd.read_fwf('output.txt')```. ```fwf``` stands for fixed width formatted lines.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60305914/reading-data-files-using-pandas

Comment: The format from website is not the same as your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import re

aa=requests.get("https://psl.noaa.gov/data/correlation/pna.data").text

aa=aa.split("\n")[1:-4]

aa=list(map(lambda x:x[1:],aa))

aa="\n".join(aa)
aa=re.sub(" +",",",aa)

with open("test.csv","w") as f:
    f.write(aa)

df=pd.read_csv("test.csv", header=None, index_col=0).rename_axis('Year')

df.columns=list(pd.date_range(start='2021-01', freq='M', periods=12).month_name())

print(df.head())
df.to_csv("test.csv")
```

This is going to give you, in `test.csv` file:

| Year | January | February | March..... | up to December |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1948 | 73 | 67 | 67 | 773.... |
| 1949 | 73 | 67 | 67 | 773.... |
| 1950 | 73 | 67 | 67 | 773.... |
| .... | .. | .. | .. | ....... |
| .... | .. | .. | .. | ....... |
| 2021 | 73 | 88 | 84 | 733.... |

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.read_fwf` as suggested by @SanskarSingh

```
>>> pd.read_fwf('data.txt', header=None, index_col=0).rename_axis('Year')

        1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12
Year
1960 -0.16 -0.22 -0.69 -0.07  0.99  1.20  1.11  1.85 -0.01  0.48 -0.52  1.15
1961  1.16  0.17  0.28 -1.14 -0.25  1.84 -0.52  0.47  1.10 -1.94 -0.40 -1.54
1962 -0.74 -0.54 -0.71 -1.50 -1.11 -0.97 -0.36  0.57 -0.83  1.33  0.53 -0.38
1963  0.09  0.79 -2.04 -0.79 -0.95  0.50 -1.10 -1.01  0.87  0.93 -0.31  1.46
1964 -0.44  1.36 -1.31 -1.30 -2.27  0.27  0.20  0.83  0.92  0.80 -0.78 -2.03
1965 -0.92 -1.03 -0.80 -1.07 -0.42  1.89 -1.26  0.32  0.36  1.42 -0.81 -1.56
```